In C# 8 / Unity 2022, why is PLINQ SelectMany + Select + FirstOrDefault executed in sequential mode?
Here is the code in question:
var raw = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var candidates = raw.AsParallel();

var p1 = candidates.AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(
        ii =>
        {
            Debug.Log(">>>>> " + ii);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Debug.Log("<<<<< " + ii);

            return new[] { ii };
        }
    );

var p2 = p1.Select(
    (v, i) => v);

var chosen = p2.FirstOrDefault();

Upon execution, it gave the following log:
>>>>> 1
<<<<< 1
>>>>> 2
<<<<< 2
>>>>> 3
<<<<< 3
>>>>> 4
<<<<< 4
>>>>> 5
<<<<< 5
>>>>> 6
<<<<< 6
>>>>> 7
<<<<< 7
>>>>> 8
<<<<< 8
>>>>> 9
<<<<< 9
>>>>> 10
<<<<< 10

And took 10 seconds to execute. In theory it should take 1 second and immediately reach >>>>> x on execution.
What's the cause of this behaviour and how to fix it?
UPDATE 1: I've experimented the solution of the first answer:
var raw = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var candidates = raw.AsParallel()
    .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism);

var p1 = candidates.AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(
        ii =>
        {
            Debug.Log(">>>>> " + ii);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Debug.Log("<<<<< " + ii);
            return new[] { ii };
        }
    );

var p2 = p1.Select(
    (v, i) => v);

var chosen = p2.FirstOrDefault();

the result is still broken:
>>>>> 3
<<<<< 3
>>>>> 2
<<<<< 2
>>>>> 1
<<<<< 1
>>>>> 4
<<<<< 4
>>>>> 5
<<<<< 5
>>>>> 6
<<<<< 6
>>>>> 7
<<<<< 7
>>>>> 8
<<<<< 8
>>>>> 9
<<<<< 9
>>>>> 10
<<<<< 10


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/merge-options-in-plinq?

How many cores does your machine have?

@GSerg I haven't verify but the first answer dismissed it as useless

@AlexanderPetrov 16, also adding WithDegreeOfParallelism(16) has no effect here

Could you run these three lines of code, and tell us what you see? Debug.Log($"Environment.ProcessorCount: {Environment.ProcessorCount}"); ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out int c1, out int c2); Debug.Log($"ThreadPool.GetMinThreads: {c1}/{c2}");

I should add that according to my experiments the second Select PLINQ operator is important for producing the sequential behavior, and specifically the Select overload that accepts the second i argument.

It seems that presence of SelectMany affects how PLINQ's internal machinery processes the data. ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism seems to fix it:
var candidates = raw.AsParallel()
    .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism);

var p1 = candidates
    .SelectMany(...)

By default PLINQ:

will examine the query's structure and will only parallelize the query if will likely result in speedup. If the query structure indicates that speedup is not likely to be obtained, then PLINQ will execute the query as an ordinary LINQ to Objects query.

And it seems that in this particular case it does not parallelize the execution.
Also see:

ParallelMergeOptions

WithDegreeOfParallelism setting. Though docs claim that by default

PLINQ uses all of the processors on the host computer.


ThreadPool.SetMinThreads


"On my machine" they had no significant effect, but in some situations they can be useful (depending of multiple factors, including runtime, settings, number of CPUs available).

Only ThreadPool.SetMinThreads and WithDegreeOfParallelism helped me.

@AlexanderPetrov yes, this can have effect too. Though not in my case (I have tested with "vanilla" .NET 8 runtime), so I have not added them to the answer. But it is worth mentioning too, will add later.

thanks a lot, unfortunately ForceParallelism is also broken, see my UPDATE 1. I wonder if it should be combined with ParallelMergeOptions

@tribbloid potentially you might need all the mentioned options. Though as I wrote - I've used the "vanilla" runtime, unity might have additional effect.

What is "vanilla" runtime? Should Unity be using C# vanilla library with mono? The query optimiser should be identical

@tribbloid "vanilla" is .NET 8 (which has reproduced the problem for me). Mono is not a "vanilla" runtime. "The query optimiser should be identical" - yes, AFAIK.

I'll add more option, but Mono should only be a different interpreter of MSIL, which is far below the query optimiser and shouldn't be affected by runtime.

If you are using .NET 8 from microsoft, are you sure you have run my program with SelectMany + Select + FirstOrDefault? your program appears to be massively simplified

@tribbloid yes, I used your code (minus second AsParallel call).

I can confirm that the .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism) solves the problem in my PC. My experiment is here.

The below statement does not execute immediately but is deferred.
var p1 = candidates.AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(......

It's executed when the next line is called.
var p2 = p1.Select(...

You can update it to
var p2 = p1.AsParallel().Select(

And it should execute within few seconds. My tests show it to execute in approx 3 secs.

"But this is not a parallel query." - why do you think so?

it is a parallel query in fact, in IDE the type of p2 is ParallelQuery<...>

Thanks for highlighting that Guru. but what is the reason that making p1. select to p1.AsParallel.Select brings the execution down to 2sec from the earlier 10 secs
